# Creating packet using struct.pack with python

Tags: python

I want to create a packet using python. The packet have 4 fields, each of 32-bits. I have the sample code:

```
import socket, sys, os, struct
field1 = 1
field2 = '255.255.255.0'
field3 = 20
field4 = '192.168.0.1'

struct.pack=('!L4sL4s',field1,field2,field3)
```

But I have no output. How can I format this packet so I can have exactly 4 bytes for each variable.

Comment: Careful there, the `=` in the last line is replacing the `struct.pack` function with a tuple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> struct.pack('!L4sL4s', field1, socket.inet_aton(field2),
                           field3, socket.inet_aton(field4))
'\x00\x00\x00\x01\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\xc0\xa8\x00\x01'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the tuple `('!L4sL4s',field1,field2,field3)` to `struct.pack`. You need to call `struct.pack` like this: `struct.pack('!L4sL4s',field1,field2,field3,field4)` (no = sign).

Comment: `print` it...like this: `print struct.pack('!L4sL4s',field1,field2,field3,field4)`

Comment: Ok, I used another interpreter (PythonWin), it sends the whole structure module. In the bottom of the windows the is a message "Firing event ´Process Event´failed ". Does anyone know how can I format the packet please? I need 4 bytes fields.

Comment: Thank you tom. Now I have the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: Somewhere you're calling a tuple as if it were a function. Post your code.

Comment: Also, as the other posts have suggested, for the IP addresses in octet format (e.g. "192.168.0.1"), you need to first convert them to an int, e.g. `import socket; socket.inet_aton(field)`

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `pack` call is returned to you and you can assign it to a variable. Your line should look something like this:

```
my_packet = struct.pack('!L4sL4s',field1,field2,field3)
```

Note that this line expects an unsigned long int, then string of length 4, then long int, then string of length 4. `field2` and `field4` are both longer than this. Try using `len(field2)` to see how long it is, for example!

Comment: Hi jozzas, I read that the '4' indicates the number of bytes, not the length of the string. _italic_for example, '10s' means a single 10-byte string

Comment: `pack('4s', '255.255.255.0')` returns `255.`, a length of 4. Note that 'packing' a string returns a string, and so doesn't actually do anything. You could have packed the numbers and done string concatenation with the strings to get the same result. What you read probably refers to the fact that non-printing characters can also be included, like a newline or EOF character.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a strange mix of packing strings and integers.  You can pack the strings as unsigned integers like this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> field2 = '255.255.255.0'
>>> struct.pack('4B',*tuple(int(x) for x in field2.split('.')))
'\xff\xff\xff\x00'
```

With that in mind, what you might want to do is something like:

```
from itertools import chain
f2_int = map(int,field2.split('.'))
f4_int = map(int,field4.split('.'))
struct.pack('L4BL4B',*chain([field1],f2_int,[field3],f4_int))
```

demo:

```
>>> import struct
>>> field1 = 1
>>> field2 = '255.255.255.0'
>>> field3 = 20
>>> field4 = '192.168.0.1'
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> f2_int = map(int,field2.split('.'))
>>> f4_int = map(int,field4.split('.'))
>>> struct.pack('L4BL4B',*chain([field1],f2_int,[field3],f4_int))
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x00\x01'
```

As it turns out, I might be reinventing the wheel here.  Also you might want to check out [`socket.inet_aton`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton) which looks like it will properly pack your IP addresses into 32 bits as you've stated.

Comment: @gnibbler -- You're going to have to elaborate ;-)

Comment: @gnibbler -- Yeah, I just went digging a bit.  so much for my clever use of `chain` ...

Comment: Thank you! But I still have TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable with using socket.inet_aton. I'm using Python 2.4.3

Comment: >>>
>>> field1=1
>>> field2='255.255.255.0'
>>> field3=20
>>> field4='192.168.0.1'
>>> struct.pack('!L4sL4s', field1, socket.inet_aton(field2),field3, socket.inet_
aton(field4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
>>> import socket
>>> struct.pack('!L4sL4s', field1, socket.inet_aton(field2),field3, socket.inet_
aton(field4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @netfreak, Probably you were trying to call struct.pack after you replaced it with a tuple - see my comment on the question

Comment: gnibbler, I created the packet and assigned it to a variable, but when I print it if full of junk, do you know why? I cannot see a single data. >>> import crear_packt
   ☺     ¶ ☺   <        └¿☺☻└¿☻☻